# Fail on docker push image to AWS ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I have one EC2 machine and 2 repositories in ECR with the same permissions.
I have docker on this machine.
I successfully log into this ECR.

If I build an image for one of the repositories, it is successfully pushed to ECR.
If I do the same for another repository, I am stuck on this:

```
The push refers to repository [repo_url/repo_name]
43e0534dbd78: Retrying in 4 seconds
90e3aa0f1f3b: Retrying in 4 seconds
30e0d794ab25: Retrying in 4 seconds
7c03fd789dab: Retrying in 4 seconds
71091a0088fb: Retrying in
...
```

He can't push and retries this over and over again.
In the docker logs, I see these:

```
level=debug msg="Failed to check for presence of layer sha256:6f37ca73c74f2cef0ddefd960260f2033c16c84583c5507a4f37b1cf7631dc20 (sha256:99803d4b97f3db529ae9ca4174b0951afac6b309e7deaa8ec3214c584e02b3a8) in repo_url/repo_name" error="error parsing HTTP 403 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: \"\""
```

and

```
level=info msg="failed to mount layer sha256:6f37ca73c74f2cef0ddefd960260f2033c16c84583c5507a4f37b1cf7631dc20 (sha256:99803d4b97f3db529ae9ca4174b0951afac6b309e7deaa8ec3214c584e02b3a8) from url_name/another_repo_name: Post https://url_name/v2/repo_name/blobs/uploads/?from=another_repo_name&mount=sha256%3A99803d4b97f3db529ae9ca4174b0951afac6b309e7deaa8ec3214c584e02b3a8: EOF"
```

As far as I can understand, he fails to mount a layer from another image (since they are similar) but he fails.
What I need to check and how to debug further?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in AMI policy, which allowed push only to one specific repository.